# TensorFlow 1.8.0, eager execution and comparison don't behave as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the TensorFlow programmer guide the [Flow Control/FizzBuzz](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager) example shows:

```
num = tf.constant(num)
if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
```

However, that doesn't work for me.

```
fiver % 5 == 0
False
```

The only way I have gotten this to work successfully is by using:

```
(num % 5).numpy() == 0
```

Are python comparisons supposed to work with the `EagerTensor` type? `tf.equal()` works, of course, but the example shows direct comparisons like `== 0`.

Comment: Not sure if you've noticed that but there is a [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18960) which has mentioned this problem. Unfortunately, it hasn't been solved.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the link. I was not aware of that issue.
My googling failed me. :)

Comment: It appears the docs have since been updated: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager#dynamic_control_flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in the documentation. If you look at [the source of the equality operator of the `Tensor` object](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L620),

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    # Necessary to support Python's collection membership operators
    return id(self) == id(other)
```

So `my_boolean_tensor==True` (or `False`) will always return `False` because a tensor object is not the `True` or `False` object.

If I understand the comment in that operator correctly, this behavior is not likely to change.